# Error reading Json from PHP into C#

Tags: c#, php, json

I'm receiving this error when trying to read a `JObject` in `C#` from `PHP`, it is the result of a basic query `"SELECT * FROM items"...`

`Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.`

PHP

```
$query = ($_POST["test"]);

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)
{
    $jsonResult = json_encode($result);
}   

echo $jsonResult;
```

C#

```
public JObject GetThat()
{
    HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();

    Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();

    string phpResponse = Answer.ToString();
    JObject myResult = JObject.Parse(phpResponse);

    return myResult;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Could you tell us what is in the JSON variable?

Comment: You should probably see the output `phpResponse` yourself by adding a breakpoint to see if it is really valid JSON

Comment: this is the same database, same query http://www.topofsteel.com/PHP/test-database.php

Comment: When does `$_POST["test"]` become a query?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Answer.ToString()` won't return the stream contents as a string. Try something like this.

```
public JObject GetThat()
{
    HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();

    string phpResponse = string.Empty;
    using(StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(WebResp.GetResponseStream()))
        phpResponse = rdr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    JObject myResult = JObject.Parse(phpResponse);

    return myResult;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was the array type.

```
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
```

does not work, but

```
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

and

```
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

do. Does anyone have any idea why? Thanks.